# Call custom function before login in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I want to call a custom function before login using the entered login & password and if that function returns `true` than user should proceed to login.

I have tried `add_action('wp_login', 'do_anything');` to do this but it called my custom function after login.

Is there any way to do call custom function before login?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the [wp_authenticate](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate) action hook.

> This action is located inside of `wp_signon`. In contrast to the `wp_login` action, it is executed *before* the WordPress authentication process.

EDIT: You didn't include much info in your post, but the [wp_authenticate_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_authenticate_user) filter may also be useful.

> The `wp_authenticate_user` filter hook is used to perform additional validation/authentication any time a user logs in to WordPress.