# Verify wordpress login credentials to api first before authenticated by wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I want to verify email id and password with external API before the wordpress authentication.
I have used filters to get it done but its authenticate with wordpress first.

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'verify_auth', 20, 3 );

function verify_auth( $user, $username, $password ){


}
```

Comment: I think you can create a custom login form then call your function before calling `wp_signon()`.

Comment: You might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231688/call-custom-function-before-login-in-wordpress

Comment: I have tried with `wp_authenticate_user`, it gives me login details if i tried with username and password but not worked if i tried with email id and password. please suggest with email id. if the user is not available in wordpress but available in api then i want to redirect to register page if its available at both then allow to login

Comment: @DavidAngulo-- I require a email id to check with api.